What's output offset voltage for this mismatched mixer?

Consider the active mixer shown in the figure below where the LO has abrupt edges and a 50%
duty cycle. Also, channel-length modulation and body effect are negligible.
The load resistors
exhibit mismatch, but the circuit is otherwise symmetric. Assume \$1\$ carries a bias current of \$_{}\$.
Determine the output offset voltage.


$$V^+_{IF}(t)  = V_{DD} - I^+_{IF}(t) R_D $$
$$V^-_{IF}(t)  = V_{DD} - I^-_{IF}(t) (1 + \alpha R_D) $$
$$V_{IF}(t) = V^+_{IF}(t) - V^-_{IF}(t) $$
$$\Rightarrow V_{IF}(t) = I^-_{IF}(t) (1 + \alpha R_D) - I^+_{IF}(t) R_D $$
$$\Rightarrow V_{IF}(t) = \biggl( I^-_{IF}(t)  - I^+_{IF}(t) \biggl) R_D +  \alpha I^-_{IF}(t) R_D$$
$$I^+_{IF}(t) = I_{RF}(t) \biggl( \frac{1} {2} + \frac{2} {\pi} \cos ( \omega_{LO} t) \biggl)$$
$$I^-_{IF} = I_{RF}(t) \biggl( \frac{1} {2} - \frac{2} {\pi} \cos ( \omega_{LO} t) \biggl)$$
$$I^+_{IF}(t) - I^-_{IF}(t) = \frac{4} {\pi} \cos ( \omega_{LO} t) I_{RF} (t)$$
$$I_{RF} (t) = I_{DC} + g_{m1} V_{RF} (t) $$
$$\Rightarrow V_{IF} (t) = \frac{4} {\pi} \cos ( \omega_{LO} t) I_{RF} (t) R_D + \alpha I_{RF}(t) \left( \frac{1} {2} - \frac{2} {\pi} \cos ( \omega_{LO} t )  \right) R_D$$
$$\Rightarrow V_{IF} (t) = \left( \frac{4} {\pi} \cos ( \omega_{LO} t)  + \alpha  \left( \frac{1} {2} - \frac{2} {\pi} \cos ( \omega_{LO} t )  \right) \right) I_{RF}(t) R_D$$
$$\Rightarrow V_{IF} (t) = \left( \frac{4} {\pi} \cos ( \omega_{LO} t)  + \alpha  \left( \frac{1} {2} - \frac{2} {\pi} \cos ( \omega_{LO} t )  \right) \right) R_D \left(I_{DC} + g_{m1} V_{RF} (t) \right)$$
However, the author gives me this answer.
$$A_V = \frac{V_{IF} (t)} {V_{RF} (t)} = g_{m1} R_D (2 - \alpha)$$

The image has a source, please cite it and provide the source

@VoltageSpike the image was given by my teacher. I don't know how he finds it.

Looks to me that the author is not even calculating the offset. Why he gives the gain equation instead of the output offset voltage is a mystery.

@a360pilot how will handle this question? Can you write you  answer below?

Given the assumptions of the question, we can calculate the DC offset at the output by noting that since channel-length modulation is ignored, the average current in each branch is simply equal to \$I_{SS}/2\$:
$$\Delta V_{out} = V_{IF}^{+} - V_{IF}^{-} = V_{DD} - R_D I_{SS}/2 - (V_{DD}-(1+\alpha) R_D I_{SS}/2) = \alpha R_D I_{SS}/2.$$

But $R_D \neq (1+\alpha) R_D$ which suggests it's not symmetric. how can you assume it's $\mbox{$ \Large \frac{I_{SS}} {2} $}$ for each branch.

You are on the right track. However, you must convince yourself that with $\lambda = 0$, the current division in a differential pair depends only on $\Delta V_{GS}$ as long as both devices remain in saturation. The output has no way of affecting the current division with $r_o = \infty$.

You also have to assume $g_{m2} = g_{m3}$. However, the question doesn't mention M2 is the same as M3.

@kile You really love overcomplicating things, don't you :) Here is a line from your own question. You tell me what it means:
but the circuit is otherwise symmetric.
